# disable attribute is not getting removed from the HTML select dropdown

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have two HTML dropdowns. The second one is dynamically created using jQuery. Both having same CSS class "inputFormDrop". In `$(document).ready(function(){});` I am disabling all dropdowns using the common class.

```
$('.inputFormDrop').attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

But when enabling I want to enable only the 2nd one (the dynamically created one).
So I used it id to enable it.

```
$('#jobDropDown1').removeAttr("disabled");
```

But it is not getting enabled. If I do the same thing to the 1st dropdown it works.
Can any body give a solution?

Comment: check if you are spelling it correctly.

Comment: Make sure the `removeAttr` call comes after the new element has been appended to the page. It should work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Ssnu6/

Comment: Could you by chance post a more complete sample of what you're doing? It sounds like you have the idea right; it could be a simple syntax error...

Comment: Could you add the rest of the `<script>` that is relevant. We need to see how the dynamic `<select>` is created. Have you [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)d the first one and therefore have a _duplicate_ `id`?

Comment: check that you dont have second id "jobDropDown1". If you use jquery 1.6.* you should use .prop() instead of attr() when adding properties.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i try it on jsfiddle but it works for me you can see the `demo` from here
 [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GtJnT/)

```
<select class="inputFormDrop">
    <option value="">first drop down</option>
</select>


<select class="inputFormDrop" id="jobDropDown1">
    <option value="">2nd drop down</option>
</select>
```

And the js for the is below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.inputFormDrop').attr('disabled',true);
    $('#enable').click(function(){
        $('#jobDropDown1').attr('disabled',false);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but the `removeAttr()` way doesn't always work. Instead of it, I use this:

```
yourJSElement.disabled = true;
```

So as you fetch it with jQuery:

```
$('#jobDropDown1').get().disabled = false;
```

More on `get()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/get/).